# Passing a function arguments into an array's position

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the right way to increment an array in a loop? I'm passing in a non zero based number and want to get the right starting position for the Array.

I can get it to work using eval:

```
arrayPosition = "articleArray[" + (goTo - 1) + "][0]";
window.scroll(eval(arrayPosition), 0);
```

But I know this isn't proper coding and now that I'm using `//"use strict";` it will no longer run.

I've tried variations of:

```
var x = arrayPosition[goTo - 1][0];
window.scroll(x,0);
```

But these don't work.

```js
function scrollToArticle(referrer, goTo, showSection) {
  // referrer, goTo are required
  var showSection = (typeof showSection) !== "undefined" ? showSection : false;
  var tmpNum = Math.round(articleArray.length / 2);

  if (goTo !== tmpNum && goTo !== articleArray.length) {
    arrayPosition = "articleArray[" + (goTo - 1) + "][0]";
    window.scroll(eval(arrayPosition), 0);
  } else if (goTo === tmpNum) {
    window.scrollTo(mainContentCenterScrollTo - (window.innerWidth / 2), 0);
  } else {
    arrayPosition = "(articleArray[" + (goTo - 1) + "][0]) + (articleArray[" + (goTo - 1) + "][1])";
    window.scrollTo(eval(arrayPosition), 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? You may get this behavior if you were to pass `goTo` as a `string` instead of an `integer`.

Comment: "What is the right way to increment an array in a loop" `.push`  Thus that question is improperly worded perhaps?  i.e. reference an array position in a loop?

Comment: what does `typeof goTo`  show?

Comment: Show us where you call the function please.

Comment: `var x = arrayPosition[goTo - 1][0];` is a completely different object (array) from an eval of `"articleArray[" + (goTo - 1) + "][0]"`  Which array is the one you wish?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need for eval, just a reference to the array:

```
var arrayPosition = articleArray[goTo - 1][0];
window.scroll(arrayPosition, 0);
```

Comment: While this seems reasonable, isn't this exactly what OP said they'd already tried without success? *"I've tried variations of `var x = arrayPosition[goTo - 1][0];
window.scroll(x,0);` but they don't work."* Not that I've found any better of a solution, but figured I'd mention it.

Comment: @Santi - note the name change in this post vs what you noted.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yes, the reserved `x`, but the answer made no reference to that at all. Additionally, [would that actually cause an issue in this instance](https://jsfiddle.net/wqaL9ryt/)?

Comment: Or OP could give more details so we are not guessing at solutions.

Comment: @Santi not the x but the `articleArray` in the OPs post vs your comment `arrayPosition` - not picking on anyone here just the details are important i.e. what the actual array is, the OP does not specify but it appears to be the crux of the issue here.

Comment: Good catch! But agreed, it would seem that OP does not want to help us help him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all it was my on fault as was noted above the value being past into to array was a string and not a number which is why eval worked and [i-1] didn't.